# c# to f# conversion with interfaces and linq statements

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, f#-3.0

I'm trying to convert this c# method that uses interfaces and Linq to f#:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<ModelEngines> CurrentEngineBuilds(IEnumerable<CurrentModels> thisYearModels, DateTime startRunDate, DateTime endRunDate)
        {
            var engineOptions =
                currentModelYear.SelectMany(c => c.Engines)
                    .Where(e => e.EngineProdStartDate >= startRunDate & e.EngineProdStopDate <= endRunDate);
            return engineOptions;
        }
```

In the method above, I'm returning a collection of engineOptions - type is IEnumerable. I'm filtering the collection so that the collection only has engineOptions with a certain production range from the current model year.

I have this rough, non-working, translation below:

```
let CurrentEngineBuilds : <IEnumerable<ModelEngines>> (thisYearModels : IEnumerable<CurrentModels>) (startRunDate : DateTime) (endRunDate : DateTime) =
    query { 
        for engineOptions in currentModelYear.engineOptions do
        where (engineOptions.EngineProdStartDate >= startRunDate and engineOptions.EngineProdEndDate >= endRunDate )
        select (engineOptions)             
    }
    engineOptions
```

This task has become more complicated than I had anticipated. I've gone through a few f# tutorials to get through the basics, but it seems anything to do with interfaces and/or linq is pretty difficult.

Some issues I have:

- How the heck to you work with interfaces in f#?
- Is there an f# equivilent of the SelectMany method?

Any tips on how to do this c# to f# conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEnumerable<'T>` is named `seq<'T>` in F#. I don't see any reason to use LINQ `query` expressions in this case; the more idiomatic F# translation would use [the `Seq` module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.seq-module-%5Bfsharp%5D):

```
let CurrentEngineBuilds thisYearModels startRunDate endRunDate =
    thisYearModels
    //     v--- SelectMany
    |> Seq.collect (fun c -> c.Engines)
    //     v--- Where
    |> Seq.filter (fun e ->
        e.EngineProdStartDate >= startRunDate && e.EngineProdStopDate <= endRunDate)
```

If the type of `thisYearModels` is not deduced automatically, you can annotate it in the function signature:

```
let CurrentEngineBuilds (thisYearModels:seq<CurrentModels>) startRunDate endRunDate = ...
```

or in the body:

```
let CurrentEngineBuilds thisYearModels startRunDate endRunDate =
    (thisYearModels:seq<CurrentModels>)
    |> Seq.collect (fun c -> c.Engines)
    |> Seq.filter (fun e ->
        e.EngineProdStartDate >= startRunDate && e.EngineProdStopDate <= endRunDate)
// or
let CurrentEngineBuilds thisYearModels startRunDate endRunDate =
    thisYearModels
    |> Seq.collect (fun (c:CurrentModels) -> c.Engines)
    |> Seq.filter (fun e ->
        e.EngineProdStartDate >= startRunDate && e.EngineProdStopDate <= endRunDate)
```

Comment: Thanks!  A few questions.  I assume (fun c -> c.Engines) type of syntax is like the c# lambda operator?   Additionally, what does the '|>' operator do?   Thanks again...

Comment: @999cm999 : Yes, that's F# syntax for a lambda. The `|>` operator changes `f v` into `v |> f`, and is F#'s idiom for monadic chaining (documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.%5b-h%5d-%5d%5b't1,'u%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d)).

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use LINQ in F# without any problems whatsoever. Here's an almost direct port of your original sample (I'm assuming that `currentModelYear` is a type and you meant `thisYearModels`)

```
open System.Linq
let currentEngineBuilds(thisYearModels:seq<CurrentModels>, startRunDate, endRunDate) =
    let engineOptions =
        thisYearModels
            .SelectMany(fun e -> e.Engines)
            .Where(fun e -> e.StartDate >= startRunDate && e.StopDate <= endRunDate)
    engineOptions // return keyword not required
```

For the purposes of this post, you can think of `seq<T>` as a shorthand for `IEnumerable<T>`.

Having said that, I think that you'll find the `Seq` module a better fit for F# as it's designed to take advantage of F# language features such as Tuples, and can assist in the type inference process.

Answer (score 2):

The `|>` or "pipe" operator is F#'s idiomatic way of applying a function to a value.

`v |> f` is the same as `f v` as pointed out earlier.

Monadic chaining, on the other hand, is quite another matter entirely. You're using monadic chaining in the `query` computation expression in the original post, and it is *also* idiomatic.

Hope that helps to keep those two (fairly complex) concepts apart in your understanding! :)